# Get an AzureML environment `source` field in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I'm trying to get the `source` field of an AzureML environment using the python SDK (either version 1 or 2).
It seem like neither version 1 nor version 2 support it, although the web UI has it.

Anyone has an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My Azure ML workspace environment:-**

[image]

***Source is a part of Azure ML Environment. You can list all the Environment either by its specific name or all the list together by using the below code and the source will be appended with the environment name in the output like below:-***

Make sure you replace your client id and client secret with your service principal that has access to your azure ml workspace.

***List entire list:-***

**Code:-**

```py
from azure.identity import  ClientSecretCredential

from azure.ai.ml import  MLClient

  

subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"

resource_group = "siliconrg"

workspace_name = "siliconmlws"

tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"

client_id = "<client-id>"

client_secret = "<client-secret>"

  

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

  

ml_client = MLClient(credentials, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

envs = ml_client.environments.list()

for  env  in  envs:

print(env.name)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***List specific environment by adding its name like below code:-***

**Code:-**

```py
from azure.identity import  ClientSecretCredential

from azure.ai.ml import  MLClient

  

subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"

resource_group = "siliconrg"

workspace_name = "siliconmlws"

tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"

client_id = "<client-id>"

client_secret = "<client-secret>"

  

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

  

ml_client = MLClient(credentials, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

envs = ml_client.environments.list(name="AzureML-ACPT-pytorch-1.13-py38-cuda11.7-gpu")

for  env  in  envs:

print(env.name)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Manage Azure Machine Learning environments with the CLI & SDK (v2) - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-environments-v2?tabs=python)